# how to compare sets using hive

Tags: sql, hive

I had the following data of all transactions where each customer bought an item in multiple categories. I need to find the pairs of customers that don't share even one category.

```
Customer_id category_id 
  21          3
  21          5
  31          4 
  31          1
  24          3
  24          6
  22          6
  22          5
```

I was trying to use collect_set first and then compare the sets in a cross join, but I don't know any such function in hive. Is it possible to do it in a simpler way? My output for the data above should be (21,31), (31,24), (31,22) which are the pairs that don't share any category_ids

```
SELECT
customer_id, COLLECT_LIST(category_id) AS aggr_set
FROM
    tablename
GROUP BY
    customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all pairs of customers by using `cross join` and then aggregation:

```
select t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
from t t1 cross join
     t t2 
group by t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
having sum(case when t1.category_id = t2.category_id then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the pairs of customers using a `self-join` and count the number of mismatches and the total rows per a pair of customers. If they equal, it means all their category_id's mismatch.

```
select c1,c2
from (
select t1.customer_id as c1,t2.customer_id as c2
,sum(case when t1.category_id=t2.category_id then 0 else 1 end) as mismatches
,count(*) as combinations
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.customer_id<t2.customer_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
) t
where combinations = mismatches
```